# How to handle json object that was stringified in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, stringify

I have a question about `JSON.stringify()` and how to parse it. I have a frontend code and a backend in python (Django).

My fetch function looks like this in frontend.

```
 const response = await fetch('some-url', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
           payload: payload
        })
    });
```

When i do console.log on `JSON.stringify({payload: payload})`, its type is **string**. Then in my backend code, when i print out `request.data['payload'])`, its type is **<class 'dict'>**. I am confused why the type changed when i sent the request to the backed. I was going to use `json.loads()` to parse the payload but since it is already dictionary it returns an error and i can just do `request.data['payload']` to access its data.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: I bet that in django `request.data` will just automatically deserialize the JSON for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you are using Django Rest framework.

```
request.data
```

Will in Django Rest provide you with a parsed version of the request body. Because you are using the content-type: json it will try and parse it as .. json.

See docs here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data

In regular Django for parsing a JSON request it would require the use of json.loads like:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(request.body)
```